# Is there anyway to change the minikube installation to another hard drive

Tags: kubernetes, devops, minikube

hoping all you are doing good, my question is about the installation minikube's machine.

I want to change the default path to C: to D:

My code to install it is:
***minikube start --cpus 2 --memory 4096 --vm-driver=hyperv***

i did read documentation but i didn't find anything about change the default path.

Thanks for the early response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [`$MINIKUBE_HOME`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/environment_variables/) env var:

> **MINIKUBE_HOME** - (string) sets the path for the `.minikube` directory
>   that minikube uses for state/configuration